# Numerical Pad dot on "French - PC" keyboard layout

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have a MacBook Pro with macOs Catalina and an Azerty (FR) keyboard.
I'm using an external Azerty keyboard (PC type, not Mac).

My keyboard setting is "French - PC" and works well for everything but the numerical pad: the dot is displayed as a comma.
Is there any way to change the locale (and having this dot being a dot) while keeping the "French - PC" keyboard layout?

Comment: The linked question is not an exact duplicate, but the solution - Ukelele - is the simplest way to do this.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok thanks, I saw this solution with Ukulele but was looking for a built-in solution and couldn't find it.